# How to name a method that may or not do something?

Tags: methods, coding-style, naming

To be more specific, **how to name a method that may or not present a view to the user?**

For example:

```
void maybeShowView() {

    if (checkSomething()) {
        presentViewToUser();
    }
}
```

So **maybeShowView** is an awful name, also Im separating the maybe method from the presenting method for unit testing purposes, this way the maybe method can be unit tested properly.

In my team we have come up with names like

- maybeDoSomething
- presentThingIfAvailable

But this are really bad names

Any Ideas?

Thanks

**note:**
I could create a **boolean** method **shouldPresentView()** but this would require me to check for it everytime I want to present my view, I dont want this.

Comment: Ending a method name with `IfAvailable` or `IfApplicable` (and etc) sounds reasonable to me. But I'm afraid that it's a matter of personal opinion...

Comment: Actually if we are using Cocoa, this is the approach they take on things like: layoutIfNeeded

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet would be to include both the condition and what you will do in the name of the method. so, if your view will be shown when checkSomething() is true, you would call it like so:

```
void presentViewIfSomething() {

    if (checkSomething()) {
        presentViewToUser();
    }
}
```

This will leave no doubt what the method actually does. The downside to this approach is, of course, that if you change the condition you'll also have to change the name of the method.

Comment: This is the approach we are going to take

Comment: What if you have multiple conditions?

Comment: @Lucas Bustamante You can just string together the conditions in your If statement. If (CheckSomething() && CheckSomethingElse()) and so on.

Comment: I mean, presentViewIfHomeAndUserLoggedInAndUserAdmin(), I know it's terrible lol, just to give an idea - I'm asking because I faced something similar while building a password plugin for WP, where I have to check multiple conditions to see if I should present a password form or not.

Comment: This answer is on the money, but I would suggest updating the last paragraph. I disagree with "if you change the condition you'll also have to change the name of the method". The method/function should be named such that it accurately describes the purpose of the function but still not granular details about the implementation logic. For example, `createTaskIfValidResult`. The logic for what a "Valid Result" is may change, but the purpose or outcome should be the same because the Task will not be created unless Valid Result. 

Otherwise, you are just writing a new method/function.